# CSS HTML how to remove whole cell links in tables?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, html-table

I want to get a web page with a footer in which there are vertically aligned links.
I am thus using a table, in which I write my links like "Mobile", "Help", "Terms", ...

The problem is that when pointing the mouse over the table, links are active (even over empty cells). I want to have the links SOLELY when I point the mouse RIGHT OVER the names "Mobile", "Help", "Terms" - NOT when I point over the rest of the cell, nor anywhere else on the table.

I researched this thing over Stackoverflow but always the reverse problems (people want to activate cell links).

Can anyone help? Code is below.

HTML CODE

```
    <div id="footer">
<div class = "box2">
    <h6><a href="/error">Français</h6>
    <h6><a href="/error">English (US)</h6>
    <h6><a href="/error">Español</h6>
    <h6><a href="/error">Português (Brasil)</h6>
    <h6><a href="/error">Deutsch</h6>
    <h6><a href="/error">Italiano</h6>
    <h6><a href="/error">Русский</h6>
</div>

    <div class = "box3">
        <table class="table2">
            <tr>
                <td><h6><a href="/mobile">Mobile</h6></td>
                <td><h6><a href="/help">Help</h6></td>
                <td><h6><a href="/term">Terms and conditions</h6></td>
                <td><h6><a href="/developers">Developers</h6></td>
                <td><h6><a href="/carriers">Carriers</h6></td>
                <td><h6><a href="/other">Other</h6></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><h6><a href="/blog">Blog</h6></td>
                <td><h6><a href="/findus">Find us</h6></td>
                <td><h6><a href="/pics">Pics</h6></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
        </div>
```

CSS CODE

```
#footer {
    height: 110px;
    background: #80B2E6;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#80B2E6), color-stop(100%,#3385D6));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #80B2E6 0%, #3385D6 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #80B2E6 0%, #3385D6 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #80B2E6 0%, #3385D6 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #80B2E6 0%, #3385D6 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #80B2E6 0%, #3385D6 100%);
}

.box2
{
    width:800px;
    border-bottom:1px solid lightgrey;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-top:20px;
}

.box3
{
    width:800px;
    padding:0;
}


.table2 {
    width:450px;
    padding:0;
    font-size:11px;
    table-layout: auto;
    float:left;
    border-collapse:collapse;

}


h6 {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 11px;
    max-width: 800px;
    color: white;
    margin:0;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    padding-right:10px;
    /*display:inline-block;*/
    float:left;
}

h6 a:link {
    color:white;
}

.table2 td a {
    color:white;
    display:inline;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #54544B;
}

table {
    width:420px;
    /*height: 200px;*/
    padding:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

td
{
    text-align:center;
    position:center;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    -o-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

tr, div {

}
```

Comment: close your `<a href>...</a>` and I think it will be ok :)

Comment: Hey, thanks, but it doesn't solve the problem...

Comment: I just close the `<a>` tags and it's ok. look the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/optyler/m8JPP/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close all the link tags with `</a>`. For example change

```
<td><h6><a href="/mobile">Mobile</h6></td>
```

to

```
<td><h6><a href="/mobile">Mobile</a></h6></td>
```

and the rest of all links

Comment: Actually, yes it solves it - somehow I did something wrong my html file... Thanks guys!